# C- Print numbers multiplied by each other?

Tags: printf

I am writing a program where I am printing the prime multiples of a given number and am using a print function like this

```
printf("%d*", variable);
```

I was hoping that it would return something like

`"2*2*2*3"` but, naturally, at the end there is an extra asterisk `"2*2*2*3*"`

I was wondering if there was a quick fix to this or something else I can try. Thanks

Comment: start with just print(%d..) then append with *%d

Comment: you tell the computer to print number with asterix after it, why in the world you were hoping that it will not do it for one number?

Comment: I realize this and I did expect it to. But I came asking for a way to print x*x*x and this was the best way I could think to ask to easily get my point across. Thank you for your input :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it LIke this

```
printf("%d",variable); //for first number
printf("*%d",variable); //use this for printing other numbers
```